# Pointer to a global static variable - not safe?

Tags: c

I have file in which I have a global array

```
static char name[6];
```

and a function

```
static char* gen_name(char* dest, const size_t len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i)
        dest[i] = 'A' +  (genrand_uint32() % ('Z' - 'A'));
    dest[len - 1] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

The pointer to the name is then stored in a global variable in different header file, this variable is not static.

```
this_name = gen_name(name, sizeof name);
```

When a function in another file uses this pointer, it works well on Linux, but when I run the same code on a microcontroller, it prints garbage.
When I remove the `static` keyword, it works fine.

Why is this happening?

When should I use `static`?
I thought I should declare all variables and functions that are not used outside of a file as `static`, is this wrong?

Comment: Show the code where variable `name` is filled in.

Comment: `static char* gen_name(...)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @RaymondChen How so? (Note: the indentation of the second line after the `for` header is confusing but doesn't affect how the compiler sees it.)

Comment: To me this looks like an overactive Compiler optimizing the code in ways it shouldn't. Does the problem persist when you compile with `-O0`?

Comment: @NikosC. It looks like the OP thinks that it is a function returning pointer to static char. But in fact it is a static function returning pointer to char.

Answer (score 2):

When you declared the variable in the header, did you remember to mark it `extern`? You need to do that, otherwise what happens is that you just get a new variable in each file that includes the header. Remember that `#include` is just a copy&paste job; the preprocessor just inserts the text from the header file in the location where the include happens. If the text in the header file is `char name[6]`, then that's just what you get; text in your source that says `char name[6]`, resulting in a variable `name` that has nothing to do with the variable that you have in your other source file.

If you mark it as `extern`, the linker will then complain that the symbol was not found. That means the definition of `name` can't be `static`, as that causes the linker not being able to find it.

So, in your header file, you need this declaration:

```
extern char name[6];
```

and in your source file, you need this definition:

```
char name[6];
```

And to answer the actual question: yes, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the `extern` part, now I have a header with `extern char *this_name;`, the corresponding .c file with `char *this_name;` and the .c file from the beginning, with `static char name[6];`, the actual memory location of the name. But still, when I declare name static, `this_name` prints garbage and doesn't when I don't use `static`.

Comment: If you could produce a minimal program with only a few lines of code that still exhibits the problem, that would help. Because right now, it could be anything else in your code that messes with the contents of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be caused by a stack overflow in a different thread, marking it static would put it in the bss section, just behind the stack that would overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Static keyword means different things to functions and variables.

Functions are by default 'extern', i.e. their entry points are made public by the compiler so the linker can find them and they can be called from any compiled module.
If you put 'static' in front of a function's declaration, the function will stop being public, i.e. it will only be known inside the same source module.

'static' keyword has very different meaning when used for variables(*). It makes them non-changeable.
When you say 'static char name[6]', you are telling the compiler that you have no intention of changing value of 'name'.

On Linux running on a PC, this doesn't mean much. You tell the compiler that you won't change the value and then you change it. You lied. No big deal.

Some microcontrollers have internal flash that they can use to run code from, and keep fixed (constant!) data in.
The compiler and linker use your promise that 'name' will not change and leave the variable in the flash memory.
You can imagine what (doesn't) happen when you try to change it.

More precisely, the compiler will place all your static variables in something like .const section, and linker will then place that section in flash memory.

(*) There is a way to look at 'const' that makes it having the same meaning when used for variables as for functions. Not important here.